# Simple Where Clause in Expression Tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees, where-clause

I am attempting to build a simple Where clause.

<strike>This is the code that does not work:</strike>

**EDIT** this code works fine now (thanks to answers below).

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var _List = new List<Item>
{
    new Item{ Name = "Smith", Value = 1},
    new Item{ Name = "Smith", Value = 2},
    new Item{ Name = "Wesson", Value = 3},
    new Item{ Name = "Wesson", Value = 4},
};

// Where(x => x.Value == 1)
var _Type = typeof(Item);
var _Prop = _Type.GetProperty("Value");
var _Param = Expression.Parameter(_Type, _Prop.Name);
var _Left = Expression.PropertyOrField(_Param, _Prop.Name);
var _Right = Expression.Constant(1, _Prop.PropertyType); 
var _Body = Expression.Equal(_Left, _Right);
var _Where = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(_Body, _Param); 
var _Result = _List.AsQueryable().Where(_Where);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: Error was `Expression.Equals(_Left, _Right);` should have been `Expression.Equal(_Left, _Right);` Duh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You need to pass `1` and not `"1"` for the integer constant `1`.

   ```
   var _Right = Expression.Constant(1, _Prop.PropertyType);
   ```
2. Expression.Equals if two expression trees are equal. It returns a `bool`.

   Expression.Equal returns an expression tree that represents an equality check.

   ```
   var _Body = Expression.Equal(_Left, _Right);
   ```
3. The parameter is of type `Item` and not `int`.

   ```
   var _Where = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(_Body, _Param);
   ```
4. The List<T> implements IEnumerable<T>, but not IQueryable<T>.

   IEnumerable<T> works with delegates, while IQueryable<T> works with expression trees.

   So you need to either compile your expression tree to a delegate

   ```
   var _Where = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(_Body, _Param).Compile();
   var _Result = _List.Where(_Where);
   ```

   or convert the list to IQueryable<T>.

   ```
   var _Where = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(_Body, _Param);
   var _Result = _List.AsQueryable().Where(_Where);
   ```

Working code:

```
// Where(x => x.Value == 1)
var _Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "x");
var _Left = Expression.PropertyOrField(_Param, "Value");
var _Right = Expression.Constant(1);
var _Body = Expression.Equal(_Left, _Right);
var _Where = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(_Body, _Param).Compile();
var _Result = _List.Where(_Where);
```

Comment: Well, both `Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(_Body, _Param)` and `Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(_Body, new ParameterExpression[] { _Param })` are mismatch exceptions. I'm trying not to be dense, but I am not sure what's the issue.

Comment: Found it! `Expression.Equals(_Left, _Right);` should have been `Expression.Equal(_Left, _Right);` Sorry for being so dense.